# Сложить дни летних месяцев

Tags: prolog

Дано 12 фактов. Необходимо найти сумму летних дней (92 должно получится)

```
месяц(1,январь,31).
месяц(2,февраль,29).
месяц(3,март,31).
месяц(4,апрель,30).
месяц(5,май,31).
месяц(6,июнь,30).
месяц(7,июль,31).
месяц(8,август,31).
месяц(9,сентябрь,30).
месяц(10,октябрь,31).
месяц(11,ноябрь,30).
месяц(12,декабрь,31).

symSummer():-месяц(X,Y,Z), X>=6, X<=8, Z= Z+Z+Z, write(Z),nl, fail;
true.
```

Что я делаю не так ?

Comment: Например, ставите пробел перед вопросительным знаком. Так делать не надо.

Comment: В ваших фактах не хватает указания, какие месяцы считать летними.

Comment: @Kromster, X>=6, X<=8,  а разве это не указывает месяцы ?

Comment: @Глеб, я про код спрашиваю .....

Comment: Решите эту задачу - будете тут самым большим специалистом по Прологу.

Comment: И что, только я один этим занимаюсь?

Answer (score 1):

Первая программа, которая заработала:

```
main:-
    listDays(6,8),
    halt.
    месяц(1,январь,31).
    месяц(2,февраль,29).
    месяц(3,март,31).
    месяц(4,апрель,30).
    месяц(5,май,31).
    месяц(6,июнь,30).
    месяц(7,июль,31).
    месяц(8,август,31).
    месяц(9,сентябрь,30).
    месяц(10,октябрь,31).
    месяц(11,ноябрь,30).
    месяц(12,декабрь,31).
    listDays(L,H):-L=:=H,месяц(L,_,Y),write(Y),nl.
    listDays(L,H):-L<H,месяц(L,_,Y),write(Y),nl,X is L + 1,listDays(X,H).
:-main.

-->

30
31
31
```

Работаю дальше. Прорвёмся.

[OnlineGDB](https://www.onlinegdb.com/) -это просто сайт, программы по этой ссылке нет.

И вот требуемый результат:

```
main:-
    sumDays(6,8,0),
    halt.
    месяц(1,январь,31).
    месяц(2,февраль,29).
    месяц(3,март,31).
    месяц(4,апрель,30).
    месяц(5,май,31).
    месяц(6,июнь,30).
    месяц(7,июль,31).
    месяц(8,август,31).
    месяц(9,сентябрь,30).
    месяц(10,октябрь,31).
    месяц(11,ноябрь,30).
    месяц(12,декабрь,31).
    sumDays(L,H,S):-L>H,месяц(L,_,Y),T is S+Y,X is L-1,sumDays(X,H,T).
    sumDays(L,H,S):-L<H,месяц(L,_,Y),T is S+Y,X is L+1,sumDays(X,H,T).
    sumDays(L,H,S):-L=:=H,месяц(L,_,Y),T is S+Y,write(T),nl.
:-main.

-->

92
```

Comment: Моя первая программа на Прологе!

Comment: И чего? Решение оказалось ненужным?